# Inserting Contents of Range of Cells Into Another Range

Tags: excel

I am working on setting up a column of cells in Excel and I would like each cell in the column to pull data from multiple columns of cells from another sheet, with each cell having a one-on-one relationship with each other.  For instance, I have Column A on Sheet 1 and it is automatically populated from data in Column A and Column B on Sheet 2 (once Column A runs out of data). If any of the data is changed on Sheet 2, the changes will be updated on Sheet 1. If an item is added, it will automatically be inserted on Sheet 1.  Is this possible using standard formulas or array formulas, or do I need to use macros or VBA? Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Either

1. Copy your formula such as `IF(ISBLANK(Sheet2!A2),"",Sheet2!A2+Sheet2!B2` down a greater number of rows than you're likely to need.

or

2. Write a macro to run each that will copy your formula for you.

   `lr = Sheets("Sheet2").UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
       Sheets("Sheet1").Select
       Range("A2").Select
       Selection.Copy
       Range("A3:A" & lr).Select
       ActiveSheet.Paste`